# Facebook appends query string to liked pages

Tags: string, facebook, url, facebook-like

When you like a page on Facebook the link to the page now appears on the users news feed with a query string appended to the end e.g

?fb_action_ids=102187656601495&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=46965925417

This 404s on every single page on my site.
I can change the facebook 'data-href' parameter on all my pages so the link will work by appending my own query string (?opendocument - the site is in lotus domino)

This works but means losing all the likes already in place on the page and effectively returning to zero likes for all the pages.

Is there anyway I can stop facebook appending the query string? If not can I update the 'data-href' paramater on my pages but still maintain the like count already in place.

Many Thanks in advance for any guidance here
Pete

Comment: Some code would be nice. However based on your description it looks like the query is executed properly and then somehow gets appended to the request string...

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12028116/facebook-like-adding-its-own-variables-and-not-recognising-the-page-linked-as

Comment: Your question is already answered here: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12028116/facebook-like-referral-clicks-addingvariables-and-not-recognising-the-page-lin